# What does 'pollster' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> A **person** who conducts or analyses opinion polls.

It's how Lexico [defines](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pollster) the word 'pollster'. However, [this](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/pollster-ratings/) page suggests the term may be applied to polling organizations as well. May it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is often a good idea to consult more than one dictionary.

> pollster  ​NOUN COUNTABLE
>
> a person **or organization** that prepares a poll

[Pollster (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pollster)

A word used for a person who does a job can often be used for a company or organisation (British spelling) that does it - e.g. grocer, tailor, butcher, baker, carmaker, shipbuilder, builder.